# I want to download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Windows installer because I have a monthly download limit

Tags: downloads

I want to download the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Windows installer in part because I have small download limit for a month. How do I do that?

Comment: I removed the subjective question (are you seriously expecting someone to say windows is better? ;-) )

Comment: 1. Windows installer will not save you from downloading the big (700+MB) ISO file. The Windows installer (WUBI.EXE) needs the ISO file to do the installation. 2. So you will be downloading two things, (a) the Windows Installer, and (b) the ISO file. In the end the Windows Installation is much more likely to get corrupted than a full install. So you may have to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case select the torrent version for download and throttle your torrent.

Here are the desktop links to the torrent:

- [Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop (64-bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)
- [Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop (32-bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

You can also stop the download at any time and continue it when ever you want.

As an alternative: Canonical sells DVDs at £5.04 per single DVD (link to: [12.10](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1027) or [12.04](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976)).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the client, but µTorrent has an option to set a Transfer Cap:

[image]

Just change "Limit Type" to "Downloads", set the "Bandwidth" and the "Time Period".